# Ios 7 speed dial cell style

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I want to create UItableview cells that have circle image and text in circle image. Should I draw every circle and text in it? Is there any cell style for this? I saw Apple did this in Phone->Speed Dial

Comment: use collection view is the best choice for your question

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no it's not.

Comment: You can use UIbutton and give corner radius so it will make circle and you can add text to uibutton.

Comment: There is no cell style for this. You have to implement it yourself. Make a subclass of a table view cell and add image view and a label. Change the corner radius of the layer of the image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIButton/UIImageView according to your requirement. To make that component as circle you should set corner radius.

```
    object.layer.cornerRadius = 40;
    object.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I should also have text in circle image, so I will use circle image with transparent background and draw text on it?

Comment: Yes, You can put a UILabel on image

Answer (score 0):

I used circle image and added UILabel in the centre of image.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 14)];
myLabel.text = @"yourExtension"
myLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0f];
myLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
UIImage* im= [UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.png"];
UIImageView* imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
imageView.image=im;
[myLabel setCenter:imageView.center];

[imageView addSubview:myLabel];
```

[image]